# Replace #DIV/0! values with 0 in R

Tags: r, replace, nan, data-cleaning

```
 Session info 
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2021-08-10
```

I try to find a way to replace "#DIV/0!" values in my data frame with "0".

I thought that this would a common "problem" but in my search, I found the solution just for replacing NAs, for a direct calculation using `IFERROR`, or for removing entirely the rows with `#DIV/0!`.

My dataset looks like this:

```
> tail(fortuna_CD)
    Playing.Position Week SUM.Weekly.Total.Distance SUM.HSR SUM.SD SUM.ACC.DEC Monotony.Total.Distance Monotony.HSR Monotony.Player.Load Monotony.SD
115               CD   25                      1973       0      0           2                    0.41      #DIV/0!                 0.38     #DIV/0!
116               CD   26                         0       0      0           0                 #DIV/0!      #DIV/0!              #DIV/0!     #DIV/0!
117               CD   27                         0       0      0           0                 #DIV/0!      #DIV/0!              #DIV/0!     #DIV/0!
118               CD   28                     17987     133      2         241                    1.08         0.76                 1.16        0.38
119               CD   29                     21435     420   1095         395                    0.94         0.94                 1.00        0.40
120               CD   30                     14466     113     45         297                    0.79         0.65                 0.79        0.38
    Monotony.High.Intensity.Actions Strain.Total.Distance Strain.HSR Strain.Player.Load Strain.SD Strain.High.Intensity.Actions
115                            0.38                   805    #DIV/0!                 86   #DIV/0!                             1
116                         #DIV/0!               #DIV/0!    #DIV/0!            #DIV/0!   #DIV/0!                       #DIV/0!
117                         #DIV/0!               #DIV/0!    #DIV/0!            #DIV/0!   #DIV/0!                       #DIV/0!
118                            1.04                 19465        101               2203         1                           251
119                            0.84                 20095        394               1919       440                           331
120                            0.77                 11446         73               1277        17                           229
```

As my data analysis will include the mean and standard deviation of each column, I would like to just replace those cells and not omit them altogether as this would change the results.
Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Try `data[data == '#DIV/0!'] <- 0`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much @Ronak! I was worried that I could not find any post "solving" this, but apparently, I must be the most ignorant R user out there!

Comment: @RonakShah, post as answer?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the `'#DIV/0!'` values with 0, you can do -

```
data[data == '#DIV/0!'] <- 0
```

Since you have value `'#DIV/0!'` in the data it would have changed the values to character. You may use `type.convert` to change the classes.

```
data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)
```